# Laravel Carbon addHour() when DST ends

Tags: php, laravel, dst, php-carbon

I am using Laravel 5.5 running on Ubuntu server.
Server timezone is set to EEST.
Laravel timezone is set in `config/app.php` to `'timezone' => 'Europe/Sofia',`

Here (in Europe/Sofia) DST starts on March 25 03:00 and ends October 28 04:00.

When I run the following code:

```
    $datetime = Carbon::createFromDate(2018, 3, 24);
    $datetime->hour = 23;
    $datetime->minute = 0;
    $datetime->second = 0;
    dump($datetime);
    foreach (range(1,12) as $v) {
        $datetime->addHour(1);
        echo $datetime.'<br /> ';
    }
```

I get the expected output (hour 03:00 is missing):

```
Carbon @1521925200 {#505  date: 2018-03-24 23:00:00.0 Europe/Sofia (+02:00)}
2018-03-25 00:00:00
2018-03-25 01:00:00
2018-03-25 02:00:00
2018-03-25 04:00:00
2018-03-25 05:00:00
2018-03-25 06:00:00
2018-03-25 07:00:00
2018-03-25 08:00:00
2018-03-25 09:00:00
2018-03-25 10:00:00
2018-03-25 11:00:00
2018-03-25 12:00:00
```

Now, when I set the date to the DST end:

```
    $datetime = Carbon::createFromDate(2018, 10, 27);
    $datetime->hour = 23;
    $datetime->minute = 0;
    $datetime->second = 0;
    dump($datetime);
    foreach (range(1,12) as $v) {
        $datetime->addHour(1);
        echo $datetime.'<br /> ';
    }
```

the output is:

```
Carbon @1540670400 {#211  date: 2018-10-27 23:00:00.0 Europe/Sofia (+03:00)}

2018-10-28 00:00:00
2018-10-28 01:00:00
2018-10-28 02:00:00
2018-10-28 03:00:00
2018-10-28 04:00:00
2018-10-28 05:00:00
2018-10-28 06:00:00
2018-10-28 07:00:00
2018-10-28 08:00:00
2018-10-28 09:00:00
2018-10-28 10:00:00
2018-10-28 11:00:00
```

Now I expect the 3rd hour to appear twice.
If that is the correct output of Carbon addHour(), is there a nice way to get datetimes during DST start and end?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we can discard Carbon and Laravel here. It all happens in PHP core. We can also verify the time zone information that the PHP installation has, though it's unlikely to be incorrect unless Bulgaria has changed its regulation recently. You'll probably get the same transitions than me:

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Sofia');
$start = new DateTime('2018-01-01', $tz);
$end = new DateTime('2019-01-01', $tz);
var_dump($tz->getTransitions($start->format('U'), $end->format('U')));
```

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(1514757600)
    ["time"]=>
    string(24) "2017-12-31T22:00:00+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(7200)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(3) "EET"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(1521939600)
    ["time"]=>
    string(24) "2018-03-25T01:00:00+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(10800)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(4) "EEST"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(1540688400)
    ["time"]=>
    string(24) "2018-10-28T01:00:00+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(7200)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(3) "EET"
  }
}
```

In short, time zone swaps between EET (+0200) and EEST (+0300) on:

- 2018-03-25 01:00:00 UTC (3:00 local time)
- 2018-10-28 01:00:00 UTC (4:00 local time)

The story is that PHP does indeed take time zone and DST into account, but I've found in practice that is has some subtle bugs when it come to date maths across boundaries.

On March it all looks correct:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2018-03-25 02:59:59', $tz);
echo $datetime->format('r'), PHP_EOL; 
$datetime->modify('+1 second');
echo $datetime->format('r'), PHP_EOL; 
echo PHP_EOL;
```

```
Sun, 25 Mar 2018 02:59:59 +0200
Sun, 25 Mar 2018 04:00:00 +0300
```

On October it makes the transition one hour earlier and you don't see duplicate hours because it happens right at …:59:59:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2018-10-28 02:59:59', $tz);
echo $datetime->format('r'), PHP_EOL; 
$datetime->modify('+1 second');
echo $datetime->format('r'), PHP_EOL; 
echo PHP_EOL;
```

```
Sun, 28 Oct 2018 02:59:59 +0300
Sun, 28 Oct 2018 03:00:00 +0200
```

However, you get different results if you do maths in UTC:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2018-10-28 02:59:59', $tz);
echo $datetime->format('r'), PHP_EOL; 
$datetime->setTimezone($utc);
$datetime->modify('+1 second');
$datetime->setTimezone($tz);
echo $datetime->format('r'), PHP_EOL; 
echo PHP_EOL;
```

```
Sun, 28 Oct 2018 02:59:59 +0300
Sun, 28 Oct 2018 03:00:00 +0300
```

I don't really have a clear explanation about why this happens (I'm not familiar with PHP internals) but I suspect it has to do with the ambiguity caused by the fact that 28th October has two different `3:00` local hours but the time zone information (`Europe/Sofia`) does not contain enough information to determine which one you mean. However, when you convert from UTC there's no ambiguity:

- 00:59:59 UTC maps to EET
- 01:00:00 UTC maps to EEST

My recommendation is to either live with it or use UTC for all internal calculations whenever possible and switch to local time only for display purposes.